# Hibernate persist() blocks

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persist

I'm new to JPA and now I'm trying to persist an entity of my program using the Hibernate Entity Manager, but persist() seems to block the whole process after itself. I wrote

```
try {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            System.out.println("Transaction has begun");
            em.persist(p);
            System.out.println(em.contains(p));
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Commit executed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not open");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      ...
```

but the only output I get is "Transaction has begun". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's blocking and not going to your catch block?

Comment: Thanks mate, of course that's it!